# zooming HTML contents with zoomooz

Tags: jquery, css, zooming, zoomooz

I'd like to zoom a HTML Table with text in it. I am using zoomooz, which is a great tool for zooming:

http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/

The problem i am facing is that fonts are also zoomed, which makes the same contents appear just bigger. I want to have more content show up when i zoom, have text wrap around ,etc. probably you know what i mean.

I checked this out but it doesn't seem to have any effect when i apply it to the target divs:

-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;

Thank you
Angel

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of zooming, you could just resize the element you want to zoom to. Then, the font size etc would stay the same but you would have more space content.

You can resize elements with `jQuery.animate`, see examples here:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

I don't quite get what you are aiming at, so please give a more detailed explanation of your issue.